# Why Prison officials bought prisoners outside in snow storm?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-way-back

In *The Way Back (2010)*, Prison officials bought prisoners outside in snow storm.

[image]

In this picture, you can see prison guards carrying guns & unsurvived prisoners died in the snow storm. What is the purpose of bringing the prisoners out in snow storm?